# Finding upper and lower sum of a Heaviside function.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, summation, upper-lower-bounds

I have been asked to find the lower and upper sum of a Heaviside function. It is a combination of a Heaviside function, like: H(x-1) + (3x-12)H(x+1).

I have been able to draw the graph for this, except I would just like some feedback on what I plan to do next.

I am asked to calculate the lower and upper sum of this function using subintervals of my choice.

However, for this function, won't the lower sum equal the upper sum as this function is simply a horizontal line? I mean, isn't calculating the sum simply just finding the area of the rectangles in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: PS. I am also asked to write an expression for the lower and upper sum... If what I am assuming is correct, won't it simply be: Lower sun = upper sum?

Comment: I am just confused because the wording of the question makes it look as though this question is difficult, which is making me second guess myself.